# Max and min from all index in query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Is there way to get max and min for all documents in index, not only max and min from category "game" without making another request to elastic?

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "match": {
                    "category": "game"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "maxPoints": {
        "max": {
            "field": "points"
        }
    },
    "minPoints": {
        "min": {
            "field": "points"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some data data i have, with query above I want to get this 2 docs from category game and min 0, max 100 instead of min 10, max 20.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category": "offer",
    "points": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "category": "game",
    "points": 10
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "category": "game",
    "points": 20
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "category": "offer",
    "points": 100
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just remove the `match` clause, and add `match_all` query to include all the documents in your index. Use [post_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/filter-search-results.html#post-filter) to get the expected results in a single ES call.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "maxPoints": {
      "max": {
        "field": "points"
      }
    },
    "minPoints": {
      "min": {
        "field": "points"
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": { // Note this 
    "term": {
      "category": "game"
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "took": 8,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65406564",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "category": "game",
          "points": 10
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65406564",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": 3,
          "category": "game",
          "points": 20
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "maxPoints": {
      "value": 100.0
    },
    "minPoints": {
      "value": 0.0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that, but I have to return docs with category game with min and max from all index :) If I want to do it in that way, I would make second request to elastic

Comment: @CaShiS, you mean you only need min and max docs from `game` category?? sorry I didn't get you, would be great if you can share your index mapping, sample docs and expected docs, so that I can build on top of it

Comment: Sorry this is some kind of twisted problem. I will try to explain. I want to make query for documents with category game but aggs that i want to get should be not only from documents with category game but from all categories, so this mean that i want to get aggs with "match_all" and documents with query "match category name". It will be great if I can do it in one query

Comment: @CaShiS, Sure got it, would be great if you can provide the requested data so that its easy for me to work on the solution which solves your issue.

Comment: @CaShiS Sure, updated my answer, pls check :)